# .NET 5 - Correctly handling expected 404 or 400 errors in a web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, .net-5

I'm looking for a correct way to handle the expected errors in my web API.

For example, i have a endpoint with 2 possible responses.

- 200 OK, with a result object
- 404 Not Found, with a ApiError object, containing a small (localized) message and title.

Currently i'm throwing an custom exception at the place in my code where i know if the resource is a Ok or Not found. I got a custom middleware in place to catch these exceptions and create a nice formatted ApiError.

This works perfect, except all these (known) messages are also logged inside my log files/Application Insights. It feels weird to add a boolean to this exception where i can specify if the exception should be logged. But currently this feels like the only possible way.

Is there any advice that could make this implementation beter or maybe i should change the implementation?

Comment: Is your custom exception middleware aware of your logger or are they two independent pieces of code? If the latter, maybe you need some sort of custom log formatter which does the filtering - since they are not "real errors". In case the middleware does actually do the logging: don't log 

Comment: Check out [`NotFoundResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.notfoundresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: This is bad advice - you WANT To log - AI allows you to track this way through the whole stack. But - you should not have them as errors, as per my answer. There is a flag to set so that AI knows that the response is not an error but a valid result, the OP just does not do it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the issue is not .NET 5 - it is application insight.

Your middleware basically should tell AI that those specific errors ARE NOT ERRORS.

https://peter.intheazuresky.com/2020/08/21/let-application-insights-focus-on-real-problems-and-not-missing-data-404-in-your-apis/

Basically, get the ITelemetryInterface from ApplicationInsight and tell of that despite the error code, the request was a success.

Voila, problem solved. AI can not magically know that specific 404 errors are "expected" as normal operations - you will have to help it out.

It makes sense to track them on a website / web application level. It does not make sense to treat them as errors on the backend level. The response (not found) is perfectly valid, from the point of an API. Just configure AI accordingly.

Comment: I agree that this is indeed the problem. I will add the filtering.
So the idea of throwing custom exceptions and handling them in the middleware is correct. I sometimes also have a bad request response. For example if the users posts a object that is not yet possible. Should this be handled by the thrown exception?

Comment: Yeah. There is no alternative given that the "normal" flow is to return the object. Hence the exception / middleware approach.